# accessing QtGui objects created by pyQt

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt

So I'm quit new to working with UI in python. I'm not really grasping a core concept and i think this simple question will help flip on the light switch.

As seen in the code snippet below, I imported a ui file made in Qt. This ui has a pushbutton on it. How do I make a click event on that button? I have gone through tutorials on how to code a button and use it. I understand that. It is the question of how to access the objects and manipulate the objects that are created by the ui file. What i really want to do is see how to perform a function (or instantiate a class or whatever) when a button is clicked. that function being one that i wrote. baby steps though. any answers and elaborations would be appreciated.

```
    import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic, QtCore

class MyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('myWidget.ui', self)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

like i said. very simple question but I'm just not really grasping the core concept here. thanks you.

Comment: does `uic.loadUi('myWidget.ui', self)` return anything?

Comment: as in like a boolean value? i was under the impression that that command just initialized your interface from your UI file

Comment: It does, and from the other answer here it looks like it returns an object holding all the objects of that ui.

Answer (score 4):

```
self.ui=uic.loadUi('curveViewer.ui', self)
#where `your_pushbutton` is the button name specified in your .ui file:
self.ui.your_pushbutton.clicked.connect(self.onBtnClicked)
```

or just:

```
uic.loadUi('curveViewer.ui', self)
self.your_pushbutton.clicked.connect(self.onBtnClicked)
```

then define method `onBtnClicked` inside your class `MyWindow`:

```
def onBtnClicked():
    print 'pushbutton clicked'
```

see [New-style Signal and Slot Support](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html)

btw, it's better to remove `self.show()`, and make it:

```
window = MyWindow()
window.show()
```

Comment: You should add that `your_pushbutton` should match the object name specified in the ui file

Comment: Given that they are asking the basics of how to load ui files, I wouldn't be so certain. In my view, it is better to cover all bases!

Comment: thank you for the answer. it helped a lot. so you are basically connecting the pushbutton event with that other module. I see the process now. and i did know about the button name but thanks for the clarification.